# audit2allow behavior has changed

Tags: selinux

I have a Red Hat server in which I was using the following command to scan the audit log and generate selinux policies:

`audit2allow -a -l -M modulename`

All of a sudden now, the program outputs an error stating that it is expecting the -p flag:

```
# audit2allow -a -l -M temp
You must specify the -p option with the path to the policy file.
```

Obviously, I don't have a policy file, I am trying to generate one. Is there any reason why this command worked for the last 20 policies I created and loaded, and then suddenly now demands the -p flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELinux was set to `disabled`, instead of `permissive` or `enforcing`, which was responsible for this behavior.